# What is the joint distribution of two random variables?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

Today I was thinking about this and I have the feeling I am missing something obvious, but I can't seem to solve it.

Suppose we have a continuos random variable $X$ with density $f_X(x)$.
Let $Y = g(X)$, with $g \in C^1$ such that $g' \neq 0$. Let $h = g^{-1}$. Then also $Y$ is continuos and $f_Y(y) = f_X(h(y))\mid h'(y)\mid$.

Let $Z = \begin{pmatrix} X \\ Y \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} X \\ g(X) \end{pmatrix}$.

How to find the distribution of $Z$? Is $Z$ continuos, and in this case, what is it's density?

I thought $F_Z(x, y) = P(X \le x, Y \le y) = P(X \le x, X \le h(y)) = P(X \le \min(x, h(y))) = F_X(\min(x, h(y)))$ but this looks ugly.. Plus, if it exists, $f_Z(x, y) = \frac{\partial^2 F_Z}{\partial x \partial y}$ but trying to derive $F_Z$ looks ugly again..

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula you had for $F_Z(x,y)$ is just fine, but an alternate choice is 
$$
F_Z(x,y) = \begin{cases}
F_X(x) & \text{if }x\le h(y)\\
F_X(h(y)) & \text{if } x>h(y)
\end{cases}
$$
This shows that $F_Z(x,y)$ is piecewise defined on the plane, where the pieces are to the left and right of the graph of $x=h(y)$.

**Revised:** So, does $Z$ have a density? Notice that $Z$ always lies on the curve $y=g(x)$. The graph of this function has an area of zero. Let $G$ be this graph, namely, $G=\{(x,y):y=g(x)\}$. If $Z$ had a density, it would mean
$$
P(Z\in G)=\iint_G f_Z(x,y)\,dA
$$
But integrating a function over a set of area zero is always zero, contradicting that $P(Z\in G)=1$. Thus, $Z$ cannot have a density, so is not continuous.

Compare this to the one dimensional case: if $X$ is a real valued variable, and there is any value $x_0$ for which $P(X=x_0)\neq0$, then $X$ cannot have a density, since $\int_{x_0}^{x_0}f_X(x)\,dx=0$ always.

Comment: Do you know some paper that go a little deeper in the subject? :)

Comment: May I ask if this was a hw problem, and if so what class was it in? If not, how much probability theory do you know? This will help me give you an appropriate source

Comment: No it was not an homework problem.. I am studying probability for an entrance exam in a university though, so I'm trying to be as thorough as possible. I just had a one semester long class on probability; We saw charachteristic functions, levy's theorem, some limit theorems, convergence in probability, distirbution etc. . I have studied a little bit of martingales. That's about it! :)

Comment: @Ant See my revised edition. I couldn't think of good reference for you, but I hope the new explanation somewhat helps.

Comment: Oh that actually pretty clear! Yes of course G has le besgue measure equal to 0 so the density cannot exist.. Thanks ;-)