# Joint characteristic function of $X$ and $F(X)$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, characteristic-functions

$X$ is a random variable. Its distribution function and characteristic function are $F_X$ and $\phi_X$, respectively.

Then, we know, $F_X(X)$ follows uniform distribution. Let's say, $U=F_X(X)$. My question is how to calculate the joint characteristic function of $(X,U)$ in terms of $\phi_X$?

Thanks ;)

Comment: Interesting question. May be helpful to note that the vector $(X, U)$ is not continuos since it lies on the graph of $F_X(x)$ with probability $1$.

Comment: Thanks. could you give please me more explanations? I am not clear in which sense $(X,U)$ is not continuous?

Comment: About the fact that is not continuos, look here (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1175778/what-is-the-joint-distribution-of-two-random-variables). Basically since the vector lies on a curve, which has lebesgue measure $0$, there cannot exist a density because integrating over the curve will always yield $0$. About your problem I don't know how to solve it! :-)